# stop user changing tabs till app loads fully

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller

im my app i have had to thread the loading of xml so the app loads and does not get kicked out by the os , but that also means that when the app loads and , the user selects one of the tabs that is still loading, it crashes.

is there any way i can stop them changing tabs till the app is fully loaded?

Thanks

Comment: I assume this is using a `UITabBarController`?  Some more details to the kinds of views you are using would be helpful.

Comment: sorry , yeah it is a UITabBarController, in the app del , i download the xml for the first and second tabs , so , that information is there to use , but for the 3,4 and 5 tabs i have threaded the download of the XML

the first page tab is loaded from a nib and is a UIView with a table, what i want to do is stop people pressing any of the tabs , until all the XML has loaded , so the app does not crash

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`UITabBarController`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) provides a [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) method called [`tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006932-CH3-SW6). Override that and return `NO` for any view controller you don't want to load.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement UITabBarControllerDelegate. Reference is here  [UITabBarControllerDelegate Protocol Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)